# How to generate dynamically image URL in Django?

Tags: python, django, image, url

I'm new in Django, and I don't use mainly Python for websites. But now one project require that. I want to create API, where you POST static image URL, and and script would generate with Django something like this: https://example.com/img?image=xXgGDd5GSjfsdaskDAdsKdkSD76454dfGdDfFs.png. This would be exactly same like gived static URL. I have no problem to create API, due about this is much guides when I google it, but this generating... This is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can done

```
dynamic_name_of_image = 'xXg.png``'

url = "https://example.com/img?image=" + str(dynamic_name_of_image)
```

and then redirect this url

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
return redirect('post_list')
```

Comment: I mainly think this would download image and then generate URL. And URL would be generated randomly.